# Manipulating Json string showing dateTime

Tags: javascript, html, json

Let me show you my code before I ask you my question,For your Info : `meetings_String.TABLE[0].ROW[(j)].COL[5].DATA` is dateTime object in sql server having format `dd/mm/yyyy AM hh:mm:ss`.....my code is

```
meetingsSDate=meetings_String.TABLE[0].ROW[(j)].COL[5].DATA; //meetingsSdate now has data in the format of 'dd/mm/yyyy AM hh:mm:ss'


Meet_startTime=meetingsSDate.replace(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d /i,'');// Meet_startTime now has data in the format of 'AM hh:mm:ss'
```

I want to make another string using Meet_startTime(or otherwise)  in javascript which will be of the format like HH:MM am or pm(24hr clock would be still better)

P.S:I hope you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to parse your values into actual `Date` objects, rather than just manipulating strings in different manners. From a Date object, you can extract the date and time parts and combine them in any order you want.

Comment: yeah I do convert the dateTime object(I mean the json string) to javascript date but for doing this I ignore Am and Pm ,thats why I can't use those javascript date as 2 pm in the dateTime object gets converted to 2 hrs(or 2 am)  in javascript

Comment: The date object should be initialized with the actual date. Whether you want to present the hours of that date in a 12- or 24-hour representation is up to your presentation logic, and should not affect your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
meetingsSDate = meetingsSDate.split(' ');
Meet_startTime = meetingsSDate[2] + ' ' + meetingsSDate[1];
```